# Display value from SQL Server on a VB.NET label

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to get a value from a SQL Server column `ID` and show it on `label.text` with help the of following code:

```
Sub getID()
    Dim selquery As String = ("select max(id)+1 from picture1")
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(selquery, con)
    con.Open()
    Label1.Text = (command.ExecuteScalar)
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

The scenario is to get maximum value from `ID` make it plus 1, and assign it to `label.text`, it works correctly when I have at least one record in my SQL Server table but if I have no record in my table `picture1` then it shows error

[image]

Comment: I get a little nervous when I see an ID field being incremented in a client application. ID fields are normally primary keys and should be non-null identity fields. If this is a single user app, it might be OK but it is a bad habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the [ISNULL T-SQL function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to deal with this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(id), 0) + 1 from picture1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no records in your table, the `max(id)` part will return null, and you cannot `+1` to a null.

To work around that problem use the COALESCE operator, like:

```
COALESCE(MAX(ID), 0) + 1
```

If there is a value returned from `max(id)` it will use that, otherwise it will return 0

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `command.ExecuteScalar` is of type `Object`, so you have to check the value.

This should work:

```vb
Dim objResult As Object = command.ExecuteScalar
Dim intResult As Integer = If(TypeOf objResult Is Integer, DirectCast(objResult, Integer), 0)
Label1.Text = intResult.ToString
```

Also you should switch [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454552/what-do-option-strict-and-option-explicit-do)